# How to trigger a rule whenever users update their picture

Tags: 7, users, rules

Using Drupal 7 and the Rules module
I need to trigger a rule whenever users update their user-picture.
I tried using the event "After updating an existing user account" which does trigger the rule, however it is too general and triggers on many irrelevant events, such as change of user role, or any change the user might make their account fields.
I tried to set a condition, a data comparison between the account before and after. something like account-unchanged:picture:fid,  but 'picture' is an invalid parameter..
How could this be done?
d

Comment: Do you have the condition has field 'picture' in place? By adding such conditions you make sure the field data gets loaded

Comment: thanks, but the user picture in drupal isn't a field...

Comment: I see the picture field is a default and not a normal field. You can try the second answer mentioned here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26395/is-it-possible-to-use-rules-to-set-user-profile-pictures

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. The User Picture Field module. However in my case it's not a good solution (because of the way users upload images), so I'm still looking for different solution, to trigger a rule whenever the profile picture is updated. thanks. d

Comment: hey @dnoncoder, maybe you may get this to work with a variation of what I described in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/228279/39516). Your question is different, but I'd try to solve it with a similar "*boolean trick field*" (and possibly combine that with using the "Conditional Rules" module (for more info about that module, refer to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/245049/39516) also.